# Number of parameters to be optimized in Artificial Bee Colony

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I was reading this paper - [Software defect prediction using cost-sensitive neural network by Ömer Faruk Arara and Kürsat Ayan](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1568494615002720)

It uses Artificial Bee Colony algorithm to train the neural network. In ABC algorithm, the input is an N x D matrix, where D is the "number of parameters to be optimized" in the problem.

If the ultimate objective of the ABC algorithm is to minimize the Normalized Expected Cost of Misclassification (NECM) as the paper suggests, is D equal to the number of variables in the NECM function or is equal to the number of metrics passed to the ANN?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  We expect references to fulfill the minimal scholarly requirements and be as robust over time as possible. Please take some time to improve your post in this regard. We have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/1201/). Thank you!